# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Рассказал ему все как было"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в предложении и почему?

> Рассказал ему все как было.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь запятая не ставится:  Рассказал ему **всё как было** (= о случившемся).

Оборот "всё как было" может использоваться в качестве **устойчивого выражения** (без запятой). В то же время запятая ставится, если оборот входит в структуру сложноподчиненного предложения:

**Примеры:**

"...и я выходил с ними на крыльцо, **рассказывал всё как было**, люди сочувствовали, женщины плакали, жалели отца... [Анатолий Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок (1975-1977)]

Так вот я вас очень прошу ― восстановите **всё** (так), **как было**! [Ю. О. Домбровский. Хранитель древностей, часть 1 (1964)].

Эта тема у Розенталя: [§ 41. Цельные по смыслу выражения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146)